# Why is this object valid against both schemas in OpenAPI 3.0?

Tags: openapi, json-schema-validator

In this [doc](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/oneof-anyof-allof-not/), two schemas are defined:

```yaml
components:
  schemas:
    Dog:
      type: object
      properties:
        bark:
          type: boolean
        breed:
          type: string
          enum: [Dingo, Husky, Retriever, Shepherd]
    Cat:
      type: object
      properties:
        hunts:
          type: boolean
        age:
          type: integer
```

Then the doc says:

> The following JSON object is **valid** against **both** schemas

```json
{
  "bark": true,
  "hunts": true,
  "breed": "Husky",
  "age": 3      
}
```

The [JSON Schema Validation](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#rfc.section.6.5.4) specification says:

> Validation succeeds if, for each name that appears in both the instance and as a name within this keyword's value, the child instance for that name successfully validates against the corresponding schema.

If I understand correctly, this object is not valid against `Dog` because it has an unexpected key `hunts`, and is not valid against `Cat` because it has an unexpected key `bark`.

Why does the doc say this object is valid against both schemas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenAPI [Schema Object](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.1.md#schemaObject) supports the `additionalProperties` keyword that specifies whether properties not explicitly defined in the schema are allowed in instances.

In OpenAPI 3.0, `additionalProperties` = `true` by default (same as `additionalProperties: {}`). That's why the instance in your example is valid against both schemas.

If you need to disallow extra properties, add `additionalProperties: false` explicitly to your schemas.

> I have not found [here](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.1.md#schemaObject) where this behavior is defined

`additionalProperties: true` being the default value is currently not stated explicitly, but can be implied from other statements. There's a [PR](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/pull/1548) to mention this explicitly.

OpenAPI 3.0.1 Specification says (emphasis mine):

> Schema Object ... is an extended subset of the [JSON Schema Specification Wright Draft 00](http://json-schema.org/). ... **Unless stated otherwise, the property definitions follow the JSON Schema.**

and the corresponding [JSON Schema Validation](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-wright-json-schema-validation-00#section-5.18) spec (Wright Draft 00) says:

> If "additionalProperties" is absent, it may be considered present with an empty schema as a value.
> ...
> If "additionalProperties" is an object, validate the value as a schema to all of the properties that weren't validated by "properties" nor "patternProperties".

So the default value in JSON Schema is `additionalProperties: {}`. And an empty schema matches any instance, this is equivalent to `additionalProperties: true`.